# Where can I read about protection?

Tags: ethics, reference-request

It may be in some subfield of ethics, I guess. But I'm interested in knowing about protection: I mean, if we know someone who's doing something wrong with his/her life, what should we do? Intervene and try to help, or ignore because it's none of our businesses?

I'm looking for resources on this.

Comment: Are you really interested in philosophical perspectives, as opposed to medical/psychological/legal (more pragmatic) ones?

Comment: Yes. Philosophical.

Comment: Is there a specific type of issue you have in mind? This type of problem occurs in medical ethics. It's less likely to occur in standard moral theories. But in most cases there will need to be something going on that compromises the rights of selves to self-determination.

Comment: in philosophy and law (and some of the medical ethics literature i've seen) this issue is called "paternalism". that should help you narrow down your search a bit.

Comment: this is a great subject but may i suggest a title change to something like "ethical study of protective intervention and responsibility" ?

Answer (score 1):

John Stuart Mill's *On Liberty* is composed to address your question, when and when not to interfere the liberty of others, as an individual and as a society as a whole.

This BBC presentation is a great intro to the book: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9IM3ZKNMCk